# implementation of an orientation map for fingerprint enhancement

Tags: python, opencv

I'm implementing a function to get an orientation map of a fingerprint
image using opencv and python but something is wrong I don't know what 
this is my code

```
def compute_real_orientation(array_I, w=17, h=17, low_pass_filter=cv2.blur,filter_size=(5,5),blur_size=(5,5),**kwargs):
    row, col = array_I.shape
    array_I = array_I.astype(np.float)
    Ox = array_I[0:row-h+1:h,0:col-w+1:w].copy()
    Ox[:] = 0.0
    Vx = Ox.copy()
    Vy = Vx.copy()
    Oy = Ox.copy()
    angle = Vx.copy()#array to contain all the 17*17 blocks's orientatons
    c = r = -1
    for i in xrange(0, row-h+1, h):
        r+=1
        for j in xrange(0, col-w+1, w):
            c+=1
            Dx = cv2.Sobel(array_I[i:i+h,j:j+w],-1,1,0)#gradient component x for a 17*17block
            Dy = cv2.Sobel(array_I[i:i+h,j:j+w],-1,0,1)#gradient component y for 17*17 block
            for k in range(0,h):
                for l in range(0,w):
                    Vy[r][c] += ((Dx[k][l])*(Dy[k][l]))**2
                    Vx[r][c] += 2*(Dx[k][l])*(Dy[k][l])
        angle[r][c] = 0.5*(math.atan(Vy[r][c]/Vx[r][c]))#get the orientation angle for the given 16*16 block
    c = -1
    #smoothing process of the whole array angle
    row, col = angle.shape
    for i in range(0, row):
        for j in range(0, col):
            Ox[i][j] = math.cos(2*angle[i][j])
            Oy[i][j] = math.sin(2*angle[i][j])
    Ox = low_pass_filter(Ox, blur_size)
    Oy = low_pass_filter(Oy, blur_size)
    for i in range(0, row):
        for j in range(0, col):
            angle[i][j] = 0.5*math.atan(Oy[i][j]/Ox[i][j])#take the final orientation of all 17*17 blocks
    return angle
```

I'm implementing the following algorithm [algorithm](http://www.rroij.com/open-access/fingerprint-image-enhancementalgorithm-and-performance-evaluation.pdf) at **2.4 Orientation Image** section
but my code is not working properly, I don't get the right orientation map. Can any one help me troubleshooting this?

B.R

Answer (score 0):

The code is working properly. If you want to visualise the orientation map remeber the tangent definition.

```
 tan(a) = (y1-y0)/(x1-x0) (1)
 y1 = (x1-x0)*tan(a)+y0 (2)
```

where (x0,y0) is the coordinate of the center of a wxw block.
plot a line from (x0,y0) to (x1,y1) to draw an orientation line. Be length = x1-x0 from (2) you have:

```
 y1 = length*tan(a)+y0 (3)
 x1 = x0 + length (4)
 'a' in 'tan(a)' is the orientation angle at the pixel of (x0,y0) coordinates
```

here is a python function to do this using matplotlib

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_point(point, angle, length, ax):
 '''
     point - Tuple (x, y) coordinates of the pixel
     angle - orientation angle at (x,y) pixel.
     length - Length of the line you want to plot.

     Will plot the line on a 10 x 10 plot.
     '''

     # unpack the first point
     x, y = point
     # find the end point
     endx = x + length
     endy = length*math.tan(angle)+y
     ax.plot([x, endx], [y,endy],color='blue')

def draw_orientation_map(angles,
                         block_size,
                         center_coordinates,
                         fingerprint_filename,
                         length):

    img = cv2.imread(fingerprint_filename)
    row, col = img.shape
    x_center = y_center = block_size/2#y for rowq and x for columns
    r,c = angles.shape #note center_coordinates.shape = angles.shape
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    ax.set_ylim([0, row])   # set the bounds to be 10, 10
    ax.set_xlim([0, col])
    plt.imshow(img, zorder=0, extent=[0,col,0,row])
    for i in xrange(0,r):
        for j in xrange(0,c):
            plot_point((j*w + y_center, i*w + x_center),
                        angles[i][j],
                        length,ax)
    plt.show()
```